# Dar efeito na imagem e no hover voltar a deixar colorida

Tags: css, css3, css-hover

Não sei se é possível.
Tentei com mix-blend-mode, filter, mas não dá certo.
Seria possível uma imagem começar com uma camada de cinza e em cima, uma camada verde.

Ao passar o mouse, a imagem volta a ficar colorida?

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo da imagem original e da imagem com hover? Vai melhor descrever seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma sugestão seria desta forma: uma imagem com `grayscale 100%`, e sobre ela um pseudo `::after` com fundo verde transparente. Ao passar o mouse, o pseudo some e a imagem volta ao `grayscale 0%` mostrando suas cores naturais:

```css
#container{
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
}

#container img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#container span::after{
   content: '';
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: rgba(0, 100, 0, .4);
}

#container span:hover img{
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
   filter: grayscale(0%);
}

#container span:hover::after{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <span><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"></span>
</div>
```